# A Strange Dilemma while Solving a Limit Problem in Real Analysis.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, solution-verification

Let $g : D\to \Bbb R$ be a function on $D$ and $(c,\infty)\subseteq D$ for
some $c\in\Bbb R.$ Then prove that, if $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) = l$ ( $l\in\Bbb R$ ) then, $\lim_{x\to 0+}g(\frac 1x)= l.$

(**Please Scroll Down to the Edit below**)

I tried solving this problem as follows:

Given, $g : D\to \Bbb R$ be a function on $D$ and $(c,\infty)\subseteq D$ for some $c\in\Bbb R.$

Also, in the question, it's given, $\lim_{x\to 0+}g(\frac 1x)= l$ and this expression will make sense only if, $0$ is a cluster point of $D\cap (0,\infty).$

We denote, $\Bbb R^*=\Bbb R-\{0\}.$

Now, we assume $f:\Bbb R^*\to\Bbb R$ such that, $f(x)=\frac 1x,\forall x\in\Bbb R^*.$ We know that, $\lim_{x\to 0+}f(x)=\infty.$

---

Let $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=l.$ This means, for an $ \epsilon\gt 0$ there exists a $K\gt c$ such that, for any $x\gt K$ we will have, $|g(x)-l|\lt \epsilon.$

Again, $\lim_{x\to 0+}f(x)=\infty.$ we fix, $K'=\sup\{K,0\}.$ For such a $K'$ we have, a $\delta\gt 0$ such that, if, $0\lt x\lt\delta$ we have, $f(x)\gt K'\gt K\implies f(x)\gt K.$

As, $0$ is a cluster point of $D'=D\cap (0,\infty),$ we may conclude, that, $V_{\delta}(0)\cap D'=(0,\delta)\cap D\neq \phi.$ So, $\exists x\in\Bbb R$ such that ,$x\in(0,\delta)\cap D.$

This means, for $\epsilon\gt 0$ there exists a $\delta \gt 0$ such that, if, $0\lt x\lt\delta$ and $x\in D,$ we have, $f(x)\gt K$ and hence, $|g(f(x))-l|\lt \epsilon.$

Thus, we have, for $\epsilon\gt 0$ there exists a $\delta \gt 0$ such that, if, $0\lt x\lt\delta$ and $x\in D$ we have, $|g(f(x))-l|=|g(\frac 1x)-l|\lt \epsilon.$

---

Now, I don't know what to do from here.

This is because, I am having a confusion whether I can really, assert that, $\lim_{x\to 0+}g(f(x))=l.$ For if, we write $\lim_{x\to 0+}g(f(x))=l$ then we are implicitly assuming, that $f(\Bbb R^*)\subseteq D.$ But this assumption is know where given in the question.

Again, I don't understand, whether I can write, $\lim_{x\to 0+}g(\frac 1x)=0.$ This is because, we know that:

> If $f:A\to\Bbb R$ and $A\subseteq \Bbb R$ with $c$ a cluster point of $A$ then, $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L\in\Bbb R$  is true iff $\forall\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that, $\forall x\in V_{\delta}(c)\cap A$ we have, $|f(x)-L|\lt \epsilon.$

But, in this case, we could have written, $\lim_{x\to 0+}g(\frac 1x)=0,$ if,

> $\forall\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that, $\forall \frac 1x\in (V_{\delta}(0)\cap D'=)(0,\delta)\cap D$ we have, $|g(\frac 1x)-L|\lt \epsilon.$

But, instead of this, we have:

> For $\epsilon\gt 0$ there exists a $\delta \gt 0$ such that, if, $0\lt x\lt\delta$ and $x\in D$ we have, $|g(\frac 1x)-l|\lt \epsilon.$

Any help regarding solving this dilemma will be greatly appreciated.

---

**EDIT: After all the answers, below, I have found an even simpler way to solve this problem as below:**

> If $g : D\to \Bbb R$ be a function on $D$ and $(c,\infty)\subseteq D$ for
> some $c\in\Bbb R.$ Let, $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) = l.$

This means, for an $ \epsilon\gt 0$ there exists a $K\gt c$ such that, for any $x\gt K$ we will have, $|g(x)-l|\lt \epsilon.$

We set, $t=\frac 1x$ and note that, if $t=\frac 1x\lt \frac 1K$ then, $|g(1/t)-l|\lt \epsilon.$ So, this means, for an $ \epsilon\gt 0$ there exists a $K\gt c$ such that, for any $t\lt \frac 1K$ we will have, $|g(\frac 1t)-l|\lt \epsilon.$  This implies, $$\lim_{t\to 0+}g\big(\frac 1t\big)=l\implies \lim_{x\to 0+}g\big(\frac 1x\big)= l.$$

---

Is this a correct procedure?

Comment: For whatever reason I can't reply to your chat room comment but your EDIT looks mostly ok.  Just change "an $\epsilon>0$" to "every $\epsilon>0$".  And I wouldn't set $t=\frac{1}{x}$, since $x$ is not quantified here. Instead, simply say "for every $t<\frac{1}{K}$, we have $\frac{1}{t}>K$, therefore..." and continue with how you've written it.  The gist of it is correct.

Comment: @MW  Thanks! But why is  $t$ is not quantified? I am just replacing $1/x$ with $t$  and $x$ is such a real number which is greater than $K$. So, isn't my substituting of $1/x$ valid?

Comment: This might be nitpicking at you too much, but you first made a statement about what happens for all $x>K$.  You then want to make another statement about certain values of $t$, so you can't set $t=\frac{1}{x}$ because there isn't a specific value of $x$ under discussion yet.  You've picked an arbitrary $\epsilon$, and from that you've cooked up a value of $K$, so you can quantify $t$ in terms of either of those, but not in terms of $x$, cause that begs the question "which $x$ are you talking about?".

Comment: @MW How about this: I take each $x\gt K$ and consider $1/x$ and call it by the name $t_x=\frac 1x$ and then, I call any one of all those $t_x's$ as $t$ .

Comment: @MW I think this will fix it (?)

Comment: Well, keep your eye on the prize.  You need to show there is a $\delta>0$ such that $t<\delta$ makes everything work.  The $\delta$ you have in mind is $\frac{1}{K}$.  So your argument has to say "whenever $t<\frac{1}{K}$, magic happens."  So you have to start the reasoning by talking about a value close to $0$, and then argue that that happens to have reciprocal greater than $K$ which lets you do other good stuff.  You can't start with the number that's bigger than $K$ and reason from there, since you're not trying to prove anything about "all numbers bigger than $K$".

Answer (score 2):

> Also, in the question, it's given, $\lim_{x\to 0^+}g(\frac{1}{x})=l$ and this expression will make sense only if, $0$ is a cluster point of $D\cap (0,\infty)$.

No, the expression will only make sense if $0$ is a limit point (from the right) of $\phi^{-1}(D)$, where $\phi\colon \mathbb R\backslash \{0\}\to \mathbb R\backslash\{0\}$ is given by $\phi(x)=\frac{1}{x}$.

We can assume WLOG that $c>0$ (since we may always replace $c$ with any larger number), so we have that since $D$ includes $(c,\infty)$, $\phi^{-1}(D)$ includes $(0,\frac{1}{c})$, and so we may indeed make sense of this limit with no extra assumptions.

The above subtlety may be the source of confusion for your entire approach.

To prove the result, suppose $\epsilon>0$. Since $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) = l$, there is some $N\in\mathbb N$ for which $x>N$ implies $g(x)$ is defined (as we may take $N>c$) and $|g(x)-l|<\epsilon$.  Then letting $\delta=\frac{1}{N}$, we have that $x\in (0,\delta)$ implies $\frac{1}{x}>N$, which in turn implies that $|g(\frac{1}{x})-l|<\epsilon$.  Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, the result holds.

Comment: I would request you to please check whether I got you correctly or not. I posted my understandings in here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148408/thomass-room

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why should $0$ be a cluster point in $D\cap(0,\infty)$? As $g$ defined on $D$, the function $g(1/x)$ is defined on $(0,M)$ for any $M>0, \frac 1M\in D$(which exists since $D\supset(c,\infty)$ for some $c$). Therefore the limit is well-defined without any other assumptions.

This being said, your argument is correct after deleting every "cluster point" stuff in it. In other words, for your function $f(x)=\frac 1x$ you don't need it to be defined on the whole positive axis to have the existence of the limit, since by "limit" we only care about a small neighborhood of $0$. As long as $g(f(x))$ can be defined on some set $(0,\delta_0)$ it makes sense to discuss the limit.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding! I  would request you to please check whether I got you correctly or not. I posted my understandings in here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148408/thomass-room.

Comment: @ThomasFinley sorry I went to sleep right after I posted my answer, didn’t see this until now, I posted a reply in chat.

Comment: @MW Thank you so much for responding! I gave a reply as well...